# Video library management

Tags: video, file-search, digital-asset-management, tags

I was previously using iMovie to manage my video library until it was changed and wanted to make the library more internal than just managing files in folders. This is less than ideal. I’d also prefer an open source solution.

I use Lightroom for photos but have found it crumbles pretty quickly when you try managing video files with it.

I have been advised that Kdenlive is great for editing so I’m now looking for something to give me that Lightroom style asset management, tagging and searching along with the ability to preview files, all in a FOSS context.
Any suggestions?

Ideally it should be cross-platform as I'm currently on macOS but would like to be able to switch to Linux. Windows, not so much. This is more for managing generated content - holidays, events, kids etc - hence referencing the use of iMovie and Lightroom (for what it does for photos). For actual Hollywood movies I have Plex.

I don’t mind paying for something that hits the mark. Keeping in mind I already have iMovie (albeit working in a way I don’t like) I wouldn’t be a fan of high cost or subscription software. I’d also prefer FOSS solutions due to having been stung by Adobe who stated they’d keep perennial licensed versions of Lightroom before making it subscription only for $$$. With closed source there’s always the chance a company does like Apple and walks away from a paid product.